# Migrate model while adding user foreign key

Tags: django, python-3.x

So i have this model where I added user field as foreign key to User model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings

class Post(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Than I run

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

And get:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'user' to comment without a    default; 
we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
    1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
    2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

I understand that I need to give it default user but I don't get how to do that.

P.S. Django version - 1.8.3

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it happens migration utility's question hadn't appeared intuitive enough for me. What migration utility was really asking were required fields of User model. So basically you need to type in some data 3 times (for username, password and email). The problem is utility isn't really saying what field is it expecting.